# Dagger/MissingBinding androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, dagger, dagger-hilt

How can I solve this problem, I know there are some issues by ViewModelProvider, but I can't solve it while googling. But, maybe different errors cause this bug

*Complete error is like this:*

D:\coding\kotlinAndroidProjects\BookListAlpha\app\build\generated\hilt\component_sources\debug\com\urahimli\booklistalpha\BookApp_HiltComponents.java:134: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract static class SingletonC implements BookApp_GeneratedInjector,
^
androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider is injected at
com.urahimli.booklistalpha.feature_book.presentation.favorites.FavoritesViewModel(�, viewModelProvider)
com.urahimli.booklistalpha.feature_book.presentation.favorites.FavoritesViewModel is injected at
com.urahimli.booklistalpha.feature_book.presentation.favorites.FavoritesViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
@dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.urahimli.booklistalpha.BookApp_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com.urahimli.booklistalpha.BookApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com.urahimli.booklistalpha.BookApp_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
It is also requested at:
com.urahimli.booklistalpha.feature_book.presentation.change_infos.ChangeInfosViewModel(�, viewModelProvider)
com.urahimli.booklistalpha.feature_book.presentation.edit_delete_reading.EditDeleteReadingViewModel(�, viewModelProvider, �)
com.urahimli.booklistalpha.feature_book.presentation.profile.ProfileViewModel(�, viewModelProvider)
com.urahimli.booklistalpha.feature_book.presentation.reading_detail.ReadingDetailViewModel(�, viewModelProvider)
com.urahimli.booklistalpha.feature_book.presentation.readinglist.ReadingListViewModel(�, viewModelProvider)

**App Module class :**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    // reading part
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideReadingDatabase(app: Application): ReadingDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            app,
            ReadingDatabase::class.java,
            ReadingDatabase.DATABASE_NAME
        ).build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideReadingRepository(db: ReadingDatabase): ReadingRepository {
        return ReadingRepositoryImpl(db.readingDao)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideReadingUseCases(repository: ReadingRepository): ReadingUseCases {
        return ReadingUseCases(
            getReading = GetReading(repository),
            addReading = AddReading(repository),
            deleteReading = DeleteReading(repository),
            getReadings = GetReadings(repository)
        )
    }

    // user part
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserDatabase(app: Application): UserDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            app,
            UserDatabase::class.java,
            UserDatabase.DATABASE_NAME
        ).build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserRepository(db: UserDatabase): UserRepository {
        return UserRepositoryImpl(db.userDao)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserUseCases(repository: UserRepository): UserUseCases {
        return UserUseCases(
            addUser = AddUser(repository),
            getUser = GetUser(repository)
        )
    }
}
```

EditDeleteReadingViewModel :

```
@HiltViewModel
class EditDeleteReadingViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val readingRepository: ReadingRepository,
    private val viewModelProvider: ViewModelProvider,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {


    private val addNewReadingViewModel: AddNewReadingViewModel by lazy {
        viewModelProvider.get(AddNewReadingViewModel::class.java)
    }

    private val _eventFlow = MutableSharedFlow<EditDeleteReadingEvent>()
    val eventFlow = _eventFlow.asSharedFlow()


    // State for the edit delete reading
    private val _editDeleteState = MutableStateFlow(
        EditDeleteState(
            bookName = savedStateHandle.get<String>("bookName") ?: "",
            author = savedStateHandle.get<String>("author") ?: "",
            completionDate = savedStateHandle.get<String>("completionDate") ?: "",
            genre = savedStateHandle.get<String>("genre") ?: "",
            pageCount = savedStateHandle.get<String>("pageCount") ?: "",
            language = savedStateHandle.get<String>("language") ?: "",
            publisher = savedStateHandle.get<String>("publisher") ?: "",
            isFavorite = savedStateHandle.get<Boolean>("isFavorite") ?: false,
            bookImage = savedStateHandle.get<String>("bookImage") ?: ""
        )
    )
    val editDeleteState: StateFlow<EditDeleteState> = _editDeleteState


    // Function to update the state with new values
    fun updateEditDeleteDetails(
        bookName: String,
        author: String,
        completionDate: String,
        genre: String,
        pageCount: String,
        language: String,
        publisher: String?,
        isFavorite: Boolean,
        bookImage: String?
    ) {
        val currentState = _editDeleteState.value
        val updatedState = currentState.copy(
            bookName = bookName,
            author = author,
            completionDate = completionDate,
            genre = genre,
            pageCount = pageCount,
            language = language,
            publisher = publisher,
            isFavorite = isFavorite,
            bookImage = bookImage
        )
        _editDeleteState.value = updatedState
    }

    // Function to edit reading
    fun editReading() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val editedReading = _editDeleteState.value.toEditDeleteReading()
            readingRepository.insertReading(editedReading)
            _eventFlow.emit(EditDeleteReadingEvent.EditReading)
            _eventFlow.emit(EditDeleteReadingEvent.ShowSnackbar("edited reading"))
        }
    }

    // Function to delete reading
    fun deleteReading() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val deletedReading = _editDeleteState.value.toEditDeleteReading()
            readingRepository.deleteReading(deletedReading)
            _eventFlow.emit(EditDeleteReadingEvent.DeleteReading)
            _eventFlow.emit(EditDeleteReadingEvent.ShowSnackbar("deleted reading"))
        }
    }

    // Function to change favorite
    fun changeFavoriteReading() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val favoritedReading = _editDeleteState.value.toEditDeleteReading()
            _eventFlow.emit(EditDeleteReadingEvent.ChangeFavoriteState)
            _eventFlow.emit(EditDeleteReadingEvent.ShowSnackbar("favorite change"))
        }
    }


    // State for get parameters from addNewReadingViewModel
    fun getBookName(): String {
        return addNewReadingViewModel.addReadingState.value.bookName
    }

    fun getAuthor(): String {
        return addNewReadingViewModel.addReadingState.value.author
    }

    fun getGenre(): String {
        return addNewReadingViewModel.addReadingState.value.genre
    }

    fun getLanguage(): String {
        return addNewReadingViewModel.addReadingState.value.language
    }

    fun getCompletionDate(): String {
        return addNewReadingViewModel.addReadingState.value.completionDate
    }

    fun getPageCount(): String {
        return addNewReadingViewModel.addReadingState.value.pageCount
    }

    fun getPublisher(): String {
        return addNewReadingViewModel.addReadingState.value.publisher ?: ""
    }

    fun getBookImage(): String {
        return addNewReadingViewModel.addReadingState.value.bookImage ?: ""
    }


    data class EditDeleteState(
        val bookName: String = "",
        val author: String = "",
        val completionDate: String = "",
        val genre: String = "",
        val pageCount: String = "",
        val language: String = "",
        val publisher: String? = null,
        val isFavorite: Boolean = false,
        val bookImage: String? = null
    ) {
        // Convert EditDeleteState to Reading entity if needed
        fun toEditDeleteReading(): Reading {
            return Reading(
                bookName = bookName,
                author = author,
                genre = genre,
                completionDate = completionDate,
                pageCount = pageCount,
                language = language,
                publisher = publisher,
                isFavorite = isFavorite,
                bookImage = bookImage
            )
        }
    }

    sealed class EditDeleteReadingEvent {
        data class ShowSnackbar(val message: String) : EditDeleteReadingEvent()
        object ChangeFavoriteState : EditDeleteReadingEvent()
        object EditReading : EditDeleteReadingEvent()
        object DeleteReading : EditDeleteReadingEvent()
    }
}
```

Other ViewModel classes are written by same logic. If I solve one of them, other ones will be solve by myself...

Firstly I remove viewModel instances from constructors and declare inside ViewModel class. but when it comes to ViewModelProvider instance, it should contain fragment, but I am using Jetpack Compose libraries for this app

Comment: The issue is  private val viewModelProvider: ViewModelProvider, you have to provide it from your App Module class, like how you did it for ReadingRepository.

Comment: is it correct to write ViewModelProvider like in this link?  [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories)    I mean with companion object on ViewModel class @SunilSunny

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Well I wouldn’t be injecting ViewModelProvider in the 1st place, why do you need to create that viewmodel inside another viewmodel?

Comment: I am new to mvvm architecture and I am trying to pass data between them. Yesterday I saw that I was wrong about it